# DataTables won't convert HTML table without an alert() beforehand

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm building a page that makes an Ajax call to retrieve a .csv file, and load the values into an HTML table.  I call it in a `$(document).ready(function(){ ltm.init(); });` call at the bottom of the HTML file.

It loops over the rows of the CSV file, and constructs an HTML table in a javascript variable, then hands the table off to the DOM using `$('#myTable').html(table_data)`.  The next function, `ltm.convertTableToDataTable()` uses `$('#myTable').DataTable()` to convert it to a simple DataTable.  However, it's not firing.  I added a button to call the `convertTableToDataTable()` function, and when I click it, it works fine, and the DataTable is fully functional.

If I put an `alert()` in the convertTableToDataTable immediately before the `$('#myTable').DataTable()`, the alert displays, and the table converts properly.  If I move the alert to after the .DataTable() call, the alert displays, and the table does not convert.

I've tried using `setTimeout($('#myTable').DataTable(),5000);` to introduce a delay before the .DataTable() call, but that doesn't work either.

**How can I get this to load in the data and create a DataTable thing on my page without the alert?**

Here's my genericized javascript snippet:

```js
var ltm = {

 // local variables
 urlCSV: 'myData.csv',

 init: function() {
  ltm.loadCSVDataIntoTable();
  //alert('convertTableToDataTable fired!');
  ltm.convertTableToDataTable();

  // Bind click events
  $('#btnLoadCSVData').click(function() {
   ltm.loadCSVDataIntoTable();
  });

  $('#btnMakeDataTable').click(function() {
   ltm.convertTableToDataTable();
  });

 },

 loadCSVDataIntoTable: function() {
  // The URL contains the .csv file.  The first row of the file is the column headers.
  $.ajax({
   url:ltm.urlCSV,
   dataType:"text",
   success:function(csvData) {
    var my_data = csvData.split(/\r?\n|\r/);
//    var table_start = '<table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="tblLTMStrains">';
    var table_start = '<table class="display" id="tblLTMStrains">';
    var table_end = '</table>';
    var table_head_start = '<thead><tr>';
    var table_head_end = '</tr></thead>';
    var table_head = '';
    var table_foot_start = '<tfoot><tr>';
    var table_foot_end = '</tr></tfoot>';
    var table_body_start = '<tbody>';
    var table_body_end = '</tbody>';
    var table_rows = '';
    var table_data = '';
    for(var intRow = 0; intRow<my_data.length; intRow++)
    {
     if (intRow===0) { // First row contains column headers
      var cell_data = my_data[intRow].split(",");
      for(var cell_intRow=0; cell_intRow<cell_data.length; cell_intRow++)
      {
       table_head += '<th>'+cell_data[cell_intRow]+'</th>';
      }
     } else {
      if (my_data[intRow].length > 0) { // Gracefully handle null lines
       var cell_data = my_data[intRow].split(",");
       var blnLoadRow = true;
       if ([Some conditions under which I want to filter out the row]) {
        blnLoadRow = false;
       }
       if (blnLoadRow){
        var thisRow = $('#templateDataRow').html();
        // Can't put the <tr> content in a DIV without it stripping out all the tags
        // Also, even if I don't put a <tbody> in, the DOM will create one anyway, so strip it out too.
        thisRow = thisRow.replace("<table>","");
        thisRow = thisRow.replace("<tbody>","");
        thisRow = thisRow.replace("</tbody>","");
        thisRow = thisRow.replace("</table>","");
        thisRow = thisRow.replace("__MYFIELD0__",cell_data[0]);
        thisRow = thisRow.replace("__MYFIELD1__",cell_data[1]);
        thisRow = thisRow.replace("__MYFIELD2__",cell_data[2]);
        thisRow = thisRow.replace("__MYFIELD3__",cell_data[3]);
        thisRow = thisRow.replace("__MYFIELD4__",cell_data[4]);
        table_rows += thisRow;
       }
      }

     }
    }
    table_data = table_start;
    table_data += table_head_start + table_head + table_head_end;
    table_data += table_foot_start + table_head + table_foot_end;
    table_data += table_body_start + table_rows + table_body_end; 
    table_data += table_end;
    $('#divMyTable').html(table_data);

   }
  });
 },

 convertTableToDataTable: function() {
  //alert('convertTableToDataTable fired - BEFORE!');
  $('#myTable').DataTable();
  //alert('convertTableToDataTable fired! - AFTER');
 },


 lastFunction: function() {}  // all previous closing curly braces should have a comma after them

} // end of the ltm object.
```

Comment: I see you are calling `$('#divMyTable').html(table_data);`, but elsewhere you refer to $('#myTable')`, is that significant?

Answer (score 1):

change

```
$('#divMyTable').html(table_data);
```

to

```
$('#divMyTable').html(table_data).onload().DataTable();
```

this will make sure, DataTable is fired when html is loaded.

and remove the

```
convertTableToDataTable: function() {
        //alert('convertTableToDataTable fired - BEFORE!');
        $('#myTable').DataTable();
        //alert('convertTableToDataTable fired! - AFTER');
    },
```